# Dropdown selected option is not showing in unity UI

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I have dropdown of Unity UI and it has one option. Its first option is selected but i dont why its selected option is not showing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is text field big enough to contain this text? Try to make it a bit larger to eliminate this option.

Comment: yes text is big enough already. I have make it more wide but the problem still not solved.

Comment: I guess you can hit Play in Editor, select your option in Dropdown and take a look at Label object under Dropdown object in Hierarchy. It should be [like this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/D-YK6U7sSB6GlZZt6HaABg.png)

Comment: Its empty upon selection. I have manually added

Answer (score 10):

If you added that option through scripts you need to call Dropdown.RefreshShownValue();

Answer (score 0):

[You have to attached Text into Caption Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhV4B.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just by changing the font size of lable text under the dropdown.
I delete the font size number, and it showed up. You can try.